# ffmpeg get frame as a buffer

Tags: ffmpeg, video, frame

Used fluent-ffmpeg library

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg'); 
const ffmCmd = ffmpeg();

    ffmCmd.input(videoStream).outputOptions([
        "-vf select='gt(scene\,0.4)'",
        "-vsync vfr"
    ]).saveToFile('frame-%06d.png');
```

Instead of saving as image file how can I get as a array of buffer or base64 of frame ? Please help not so good with this library.